# Perl: can't break out of while loop with last

Tags: perl, while-loop

I am communicating with a server over UNIX sockets. The server terminates the communication with an empty line ("\n"). My client program ends like this:

```
while (my $result = <$sock>) {
    print $result;
    last unless (chomp $result);
}
close $sock;
```

But I never seem to get out of the while loop. I have to Ctrl-C to get out. Why is this, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

chomp returns the total number of characters removed, so you get always a true value if the line contains a newline.
Use something like

`last if ($result =~ /^\n$/);`

Comment: $ looks for \n anyway.

Comment: @Сухой27, No, it doesn't. `$result =~ /^$/` will match both the empty string a string containing just a LF. Mind you, that's probably best.